# How to disable button until input field has a value using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I know nothing about Angular but I was asked to create a validation for the new google map input. All I want to do is have the #lugar_continuar button stay disabled until the input #ciudad is filled in, but the button isn't disabled for some reason.

index.php, input to validate

```
                <div class="">
                    <input id="ciudad" name="ciudad" class="ciudad" type="text"
                           placeholder="Ciudad" value="" required ng-model="ciudadSet">
                    <div id="map"></div>
                    <input type="hidden" id="distance" size="31" value="31">
                </div>
```

Input type button that should stay disabled

```
<input id="lugar_continuar" name="lugar_continuar" type="button" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Reserva', 'Continuar', 'preciohome'])" value="Continuar"  ng-disabled="validacion2() && ciudadSet" ng-click="from_precio = true" >
```

Using ng-model doesn't work. I also tried with JS, in main.js:

```
var ReservasApp = angular.module('Reservas',['rzModule']);

ReservasApp.controller('ReservasController',function($scope){
     $scope.ciudad = "";
     $scope.validacionCiudad = function() {
            var disabled = false;

            if( $scope.ciudad != null && $scope.ciudad != "" )
            {
                disabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                disabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

index.php

```
<input id="lugar_continuar" name="lugar_continuar" type="button" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Reserva', 'Continuar', 'preciohome'])" value="Continuar"  ng-disabled="validacion2() && validacionCiudad()" ng-click="from_precio = true" >
```

I also tried using only JS:

```
var validacionCiudad = function() {
        var ciudad = document.getElementById('ciudad');
        var btn = document.getElementById('lugar_continuar');
        if (ciudad.value == "") {
            btn.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
        } else {
            btn.removeAttribute("disabled");
        }
    }
validacionCiudad();
```

I have tried many ways to achieve this but nothing is working!

Comment: You can do `ng-disabled="editForm.$invalid"` and make the form invalid if your required filed is empty

Comment: The form? Sorry I don't understand what you meant

Comment: Elements must be inside some form right, that form name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this: `ng-disabled = "ciudadSet == ''"`, since `ng-disabled` is valid when the expression equals `true`. If you must call function `validacionCiudad` to judge this, you have to return bool value in your function. May this will help.

Comment: Worked!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Change $scope.ciudad ="" to $scope.ciudad = undefined;

change your ng-model to:

ng-model="ciudad"

and your ng-disabled to:

ng-disabled="!ciudad"

that shall work

Answer (score 0):

You can validate it like this.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <form name="userForm" ng-submit="submitForm(userForm.$valid)" novalidate>
    <input name="name" ng-model="name" type="text" required >
    <br>
    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid" >Enviar</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ivanm07/y2t88817/